# Trying to define what should be in the where clause?

Tags: sql

Here's the code I'm using -  I am creating a new view with 5 columns (the SEWEBCAT column contents is not related to any table contents).I think it seems to be ok but I don't know what's missing for the 'WHERE' clause?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW NewView_VW
   (
   URL,
   ORGANISATION,
   SEWEBCAT,
   SEARCH_DESC,
   SEARCH_TAG
    )
   AS
   SELECT   Table1.URL,
            Table2.ORGANISATION,
            Table1.SEARCH_DESC,
            Table1.SEARCH_TAG,
   FROM     Table1,
            Table2

   WHERE CODE_HERE;

   DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM NewView;

   CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM NewView FOR NewView_VW;

    DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM NewView_VW;

   CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM NewView_VW FOR 
    SChemaName.NewView_VW;


  GRANT SELECT ON SchemaName.NewView_VW TO PUBLIC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid WHERE statement:

```
WHERE CODE_HERE;
```

Just remove whole line with WHERE clause if you are not going to use it.

Comment: ALso OP forgot the join! He can use implict joins and put that in that where clause but I suggest to do explict join removing the second table from the FROM clause.

Comment: Is there something you are using to join the two tables together that would necessitate some `WHERE` clause or are you trying to filter results out inside the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: No, I've realised I don't need a where clause after all - I was copying form a template and as I'm new to sql assumed I would need the where clause - thank you for your help, more practice needed for me I think!